# Symfony 3 : Modifying form data after submission

Tags: symfony, formbuilder, symfony-3.4

I'm facing a problem with Symfony 3.4 :

I have a formbuilder including 2 buttons ('add' and 'extract') and when 'add' is clicked, I want to add a new field in a CollectionType instead of doing the "extract" stuff.

I tried to do it with FormEvent but when I can tell which button isClicked() (SUBMIT), it's too late to call $event->setData() and $event->getForm()->setData() do nothing.
On the other hand, when I can setData() (PRE_SUBMIT), I can't tell which button isClicked() since the information isn't computed yet in the submission process.

How can I achieve to add a value in my CollectionType (and so, a new field) after the 'add' button be clicked.

Thanks

```
$this->createFormBuilder(array('columns' => array(1, 2, 3)))
            ->add('columns', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => TextType::class
            ))
            ->add('extract', SubmitType::class)
            ->add('add', SubmitType::class)
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {

                if ($event->getForm()->get('add')->isClicked()) {

                    $data = $event->getData();
                    $data['columns'][] = null;
                    $event->setData($data);
                }
            })
            ->getForm()
            ->handleRequest($request)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add or remove fields on the SUBMIT event. It's too late. You need to do it in the PRE_SUBMIT (cf: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#b-the-formevents-submit-event)

Try to check if the 'add' key is present in $data instead of checking for isClicked():

```
->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        if (isset($data['add'])) {
              $data['columns'][] = null;
              $event->setData($data);
        } 
})
```

Comment: Actually, the buttons values or indexes are never added to the data so there doesn't seems to be any reliable way to check it other than passing the request to the function (with "use") and checking the index. But I was expecting a "most correct way" to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

@Youri_G is mostly correct, but `setData` has to be called by a defined form-field instead of a `FormEvent` so that symfony knows which field should be modified:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder(array('columns' => array(1, 2, 3)))
        ->add('columns', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => TextType::class
        ))
        ->add('extract', SubmitType::class)
        ->add('add', SubmitType::class)
        ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {

            $data = $event->getData();

            if (isset($data["add"])) {

                $data['columns'][] = null;
                // in this way the symfony knows which field should be modified
                $event->getForm()->get("columns")->setData($data['columns']);

            }
        })
        ->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);
```